# who to use Instance methods for awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, instance

I have implement awesome_nested_set gem in ROR, and it has Instance methods (https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet). I have try this

```
Category.level(1)
```

but it show me error

```
undefined method `level'
```

this is also not working

```
@sa = Category.siblings('name'=>'new')

     abort(@sa.siblings.inspect)
```

how can i implement these

Comment: Have you wrote `acts_as_nested_set` in your model?

Comment: yes i have write down there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Instance methods for awesome_nested_set

```
cat = Category.find_by_name("here")
subcats = cat.ancestors
abort(subcats.inspect)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `level` is instance, not class method.

So,

```
category = Category.create!(bla-bla-bla)
puts category.label # this shoud work
```

Answer (score 0):

level is an instance method

it says right there in cheatsheet [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet#advanced-usage)

**Instance methods**

```
my_cat.root                  root for this node
my_cat.level                 the level of this object in the tree (e.g. root = 0)
my_cat.parent                the node's immediate parent
my_cat.children              array of immediate children (just those in the next level)
my_cat.ancestors             array of all parents, parents' parents, etc, excluding self
my_cat.self_and_ancestors    array of all parents, parents' parents, etc, including self
my_cat.siblings              array of brothers and sisters (all at that level), excluding self
my_cat.self_and_siblings     array of brothers and sisters (all at that level), including self
my_cat.descendants           array of all children, children's children, etc., excluding self
my_cat.self_and_descendants  array of all children, children's children, etc., including self
my_cat.leaves                array of all descendants that have no children
```

so use level with instance of `Category`

Comment: something like `category = Category.first` and then `category.level` if you have records in `Category` or create a record and then try